# Thingsboard CoAP Port opening

Tags: thingsboard, coap

I am trying to send data from my NodeMCU to my local thingsboard installation on my computer. However, I don't know how to do it. I am really new at these stuff, I saw some fine examples with HTTP and MQTT, but there isn't any info about CoAP on thingsboard website. 
There is a documentation about CoAP API Reference that says I need to send a post request to coap://localhost:5683/api/v1/........../telemetry but when i try to do it with Postman it says cant reach the following adress. I tried doing it with http://localhost:5683/api/v1/........../telemetry and it works. I saw my messages in Latest Telemetry Section in my Device on Thingsboard.

To connect to my Thingsboard installation I use localhost:8080 so I assume my thingsboard server is only started at port 8080 not 5683-> Coap. I would very much appreciate the help.

Comment: Check your thingsboard.yml configuration. CoAP protocol is disabled by default and you need to enable it: coap.enalbed : true

Comment: It is enabled. I have enabled it. But I still cannot connect

Comment: I don't think that postman supports CoAP protocol. But you can use npm CoAP client for sending requests: https://www.npmjs.com/package/coap

Answer (score 1):

After enabling coap in thingsboard.yml file, you have to restart thingsboard service on your computer, to do that use 
    "sudo systemctl stop thingsboard" &
    "sudo systemctl start thingsboard"